# Appending el in Backbone from an instance

Tags: backbone.js, append, instance, el

I'm attempting to append the html within `el` from instances

```
var Article1 = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        console.log('type 1', options)
        this.flyIn(options);
    },
    flyIn: function(options) {
        this.$el.find('.superDog').css({
            display: 'block'
        });
        this.$el.find('.superDog').animate({
            top: options.top,
            left: options.left
        }, 3000);
    },
    render: function() {

    },
    el: '<div><p class="superDog"></p></div>'
});

var Article1A = new Article1({
    color: 'black',
    top: '300',
    left: '300',
    html: 'hello world'

});

var Article1B = new Article1({
    color: 'blue',
    top: '800',
    left: '800',
    html: 'Hello Everyone'
});

var Article1C = new Article1({
    color: 'blue',
    top: '600',
    left: '1000',
    html: 'Hello No One'
});
```

I've tried putting `append.el` (or `el.append`, wasn't sure which way it went), `options.html`, etc.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do or do I have to use something else?

Answer (score 0):

Take time to read the Backbone documentation:

- the [`el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) view property is a string (a selector) or DOM element,
- the [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el) refer to a jQuery object of `this.el` which is the DOM element.
- [`template`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-template) is whatever you want, a function or a string mostly.

Optimize your use of jQuery by caching objects instead of selecting them over and over.

```
// chain when possible
this.$('.superDog')
    .append(options.html)
    .css({ display: 'block' });

// cache the object
var $superDog = this.$('.superDog');

// and use it later
$superDog.append(options.html);
// ...more code and then...
$superDog.css({ display: 'block' });
```

## Rendering a dynamic list

Make a generic view which will serve for every article.

```
var ArticleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'p',
    className: 'superDog',
    render: function() {
        // apply the template
        this.$el.html(this.model.get('html'))
            .show()
            .animate({
                top: this.model.get('top'),
                left: this.model.get('left')
            }, 3000);

        return this; // always return this in render.
    },
});
```

Then use this view inside a generic article list view.

```
var ArticleList = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty();
        this.collection.each(this.renderArticle, this);
        return this;
    },
    renderArticle: function(model) {
        var view = new ArticleView({
            model: model
        });
        this.$el.append(view.render().el);
    },
});
```

And use Backbone models and a collection to convey the data.

```
var list = new ArticleList({
    collection: new Backbone.Collection([{
            id: '1A',
            color: 'black',
            top: '300',
            left: '300',
            html: 'hello world'

        },
        {
            id: '1B',
            color: 'blue',
            top: '800',
            left: '800',
            html: 'Hello Everyone'
        },
        {
            id: '1C',
            color: 'blue',
            top: '600',
            left: '1000',
            html: 'Hello No One'
        }
    ])
});

list.render();
```

Comment: Sorry I guess from an outside perspective it wouldn't make sense. I'm looking to have each `new Article1` append html into the original so that I can make multiple instances with minor differences instead of making and styling each individual article

Comment: @Elivious all articles inside of the `.superDog` div or a new `.superDog` div for each?

Comment: @Elivious I added a simple dynamic list rendering with backbone.